Is it possible to generate class attributes without using HTML?
React-Markdown lets you use HTML in your Markdown, but it requires adding the (±60kb minzipped) rehype-raw package (and if you're not careful, you could potentially allow unsafe HTML in).
My question is, is there any way of not doing that, but still somehow (through Markdown) indicating that I want to add a class to some output?
In other words, if I had the Markdown text:
<ReactMarkdown>
this is an [example]{.someclass} of a class
</ReactMarkdown>

it would render as:
 this is an <span class="someclasss">example</span> of a class

I don't care about the specific format (i.e., it doesn't have to be [text]{.class}): I'll happily use any plugin or configuration option that lets me add classes without HTML.  However, I haven't been able to find any way to achieve this without HTML so far.
